# Data extract from excel and add a new column to database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am extracting data from excel sheet into sql database using

```
Insert INTO dbo.tablex 
Select * FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; Database=C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx.xlsx',
 'SELECT * FROM [xxx$]')
GO
```

Which works perfectly.
Now I need a new column in my table of date and it should automatically get the current date.

So I created date column with default as current_timestamp but now when I run the insert command it says columns does not match with schema of table definition.

I need date to be automatically filled in with current date in all rows once the insert command is fired.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, its not possible from SQL and you would have to make changes in the Excel file by adding a column of Date.